# Data fetched with axios flickering on page load

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, fetch, gatsby

I'm building out a new marketing website for my company in Gatsby, utilizing `axios` to fetch data from a REST api to dynamically display a list of dealers, and then dynamically displaying the contact information of the chosen dealer throughout the site. This is done by setting a cookie, which carries the ID of the dealer on the API, and then will fetch that dealer's info based on the cookie. However, I'm encountering an issue where the name of the dealer, which I'm currently displaying in the header, flickers on every page load. It looks bad, so I'm wondering if there is a way to either cache that data, or not force it to fetch on every page load and eliminate the flicker.  I'm still in development, so I've got it [staged on Netlify here](https://onedaydoors.netlify.app), and you can take a look at the live version.

Here is my hook.

**use-fetch.ts**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) return;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setStatus('fetching');
      const result = await axios(url);
      setData(result.data);
      setStatus('fetched');
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { status, data };
};
```

I'm then able to consume this in the pages like so:

```
const [query] = useState('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/');
const url = query && 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${cookie}';
const { data } = useFetch(url);
```

This sets an initial state `users/1/` that will display the information for the first dealer unless a cookie is set.

I use this in a layout component, and I can pass the `data` prop down to my `Header` component.

**app-layout.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Logo from '../../assets/svg/logo.svg';

import { Header } from '../header/Header';
import { Footer } from '../footer/Footer';
import { Devtools } from '../devtools/Devtools';

import s from './AppLayout.scss';

import { useCookie } from 'hooks/use-cookie';
import { useFetch } from 'hooks/use-fetch';

interface AppLayoutProps {
  menuItems: any;
  children: ReactNode;
}

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// tslint:disable no-default-export
export default ({ children, menuItems }: AppLayoutProps) => {
  // copyright year
  const [year, setDate] = useState<any>();

  // setting cookie to be referenced in the useFetch hook, setting the query for dealer specific information
  const [cookie] = useCookie('one-day-location', '1');

  // the API call
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/');
  const url = query && `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${cookie}`;
  const { data } = useFetch(url);

  const getYear = () => setDate(new Date().getFullYear());

  useEffect(() => {
    getYear();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={s.layout}>
      <Header menuItems={menuItems} data={data}></Header>

      {children}

      <Footer menuItems={menuItems} logo={<Logo />} year={year} />

      {isDev && <Devtools />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this is my `use-cookie` hook that is referenced throughout these components:

**use-cookie.ts**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

/**
 * Custom hook creates and returns cookie values.
 */
export const useCookie = (key: string, value: string) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const [cookie] = useState(() => {
    if (cookies.get(key)) {
      return cookies.get(key);
    }
    cookies.set(key, value);
  });

  const updateCookie = (value: string) => {
    removeItem(value);
    cookies.set(key, value);
  };

  const removeItem = (key: string) => {
    cookies.remove(key);
  };

  return [cookie, updateCookie, removeItem];
};
```

If you notice though, it flickers on every page load. Is there a way to store and display that data differently so that it won't do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I can understand with the given  code snippet is, that some how header component is getting unmounted and mounted again and again on every route changes. which cause the api calls to happen again and again. As you are using gatsbyjs, you might want to implement layout components. See this link for more info:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/recipes/pages-layouts/#creating-a-layout-component

Comment: I'm currently using a page layout, I've updated my question to reflect that!

Comment: Can you also just paste the code for useCookie

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Comment: When i am seeing the network call in the netlify link that you have given ,this (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 ) API call is happening on very header link click. so when this api call will happen definitely the flicker will come.  I am unable to see any thing wrong here but , try to put a console log before return in app-layout.tsx, and check whether that console is happening repeatedly. If it is happneing we need to see why that's happening.

Comment: I added a console.log to return the data, and the API is being called on every link click, you're right. Is there a way to minimize that occurring?

Comment: Essentially if we are using layout component, that should not happen. Explore more in gatsbyjs docs.I have nothing on top of my head. I also have to read the docs :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to try some other things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was able to figure out a better solution with a bit of digging. Rather than trying to debug the hook that I built, I'm using [axios-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks), which has all of the same functionality that I needed, but solves the problem. In my layout, I've got the data being fetched like so:

```
const [cookie, updateCookie] = useCookie('one-day-location', '1');

const [{ data, loading, error }] = useAxios(
  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${cookie}`,
);
```

And I'm then able to pass the data down to my `Header` component, but it doesn't load the API multiple times, and eliminates the flickering. I can absolutely add more documentation here in my answer if anyone has any more questions.